# Error deleting records from a SwiftUI List and Realm

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swiftui, swiftui-list

Has anyone been able to successfully integrate `Realm` with `SwiftUI`, especially deleting records/rows from a `SwiftUI List`? I have tried a few different methods but no matter what I do I get the same error. After reading some related threads I found out that other people have the same issue.

The following code successfully presents all of the items from `Realm` in a `SwiftUI List`, I can create new ones and they show up in the List as expected, my issues is when I try to delete records from the List by either manually pressing a button or by left-swiping to delete the selected row, I get an Index is out of bounds error.

Any idea what could be causing the error?

Here is my code:

### Realm Model

```
class Dog: Object {
    @objc dynamic var name = ""
    @objc dynamic var age = 0
    @objc dynamic var createdAt = NSDate()

    @objc dynamic var userID = UUID().uuidString
    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "userID"
    }
}
```

### SwiftUI Code

```
class BindableResults<Element>: ObservableObject where Element: RealmSwift.RealmCollectionValue {
    var results: Results<Element>

    private var token: NotificationToken!

    init(results: Results<Element>) {
        self.results = results
        lateInit()
    }
    func lateInit() {
        token = results.observe { [weak self] _ in
            self?.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    deinit {
        token.invalidate()
    }
}

struct DogRow: View {
    var dog = Dog()
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Text(dog.name)
            Text("\(dog.age)")
        }
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {

    @ObservedObject var dogs = BindableResults(results: try! Realm().objects(Dog.self))

    var body: some View {
        VStack{

        List{
            ForEach(dogs.results, id: \.name) { dog in
                DogRow(dog: dog)
            }.onDelete(perform: deleteRow )
        }

            Button(action: {
                try! realm.write {
                    realm.delete(self.dogs.results[0])
                }
            }){
                Text("Delete User")
            }
        }
    }

    private func deleteRow(with indexSet: IndexSet){
        indexSet.forEach ({ index in
            try! realm.write {
                realm.delete(self.dogs.results[index])
            }
        })
    }
}
```

### Error

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘RLMException’, reason: ‘Index 23 is out of bounds (must be less than 23).’

Of course, the 23 changes depending on how many items are in the Realm database, in this case, I had 24 records when I swiped and tapped the delete button.

FYI - The error points to the AppDelegate file with a `Thread 1: signal SIGABRT`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how i do this. This is without realm operations but i hope u get the idea where you can put the realm stuff. (I also almost never use the realm objects directly but instead convert them to structs or classes.)

```
import Foundation
import Realm
import Combine
import SwiftUI

struct dogs: Hashable {
  let name: String
}

class RealmObserverModel: ObservableObject {

  var didChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
  @Published var dogsList: [dogs] = [dogs(name: "Dog 1"), dogs(name: "Dog 2")]

  // get your realm objects here and set it to
  // the @Publsished var
  func getDogs() {
    let count = dogsList.count + 1
    dogsList.append(dogs(name: "Dog \(count)"))
  }

  // get your realm objects here and set it to
  // the @Publsished var
  func deletetDogs() {
   _ = dogsList.popLast()
  }
}

/// Master View
struct DogView: View {
  @EnvironmentObject var observer: RealmObserverModel

  var body: some View {

    VStack{
      DogsListView(dogsList: $observer.dogsList)

      HStack{
      Button(action: {
        self.observer.getDogs()
      }) {
      Text("Get more dogs")
      }

        Button(action: {
          self.observer.deletetDogs()
        }) {
        Text("Delete dogs")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

// List Subview wiht Binding
struct DogsListView: View {
  @Binding var dogsList: [dogs]

  var body: some View {
    VStack{
      List{
        ForEach(dogsList, id:\.self) { dog in
          Text("\(dog.name)")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

struct DogView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
  static var previews: some View {
    DogView().environmentObject(RealmObserverModel())
  }
}
```

Comment: I really appreciate your effort but I think my main issue is with the way  Realm works, but I will give it a try. So, have you been able to make Realm work with SiwftUI?

Comment: Yes i am doing this in one of my apps but  i use this indirect way via the RealmObserverModel() model, so i can be sure i have the correct result.
Binding the realm result directly to a Bindable or Observable can be critical imo, async issues, try catch ... etc.
i use it in the app: https://apps.apple.com/us/app/arvie-ar-video-walls/id1489863285
When you save a ar studio....

Comment: I'm still a little confused as to how would I incorporate the Realm objects in your code but I will give a try and let you know how it goes. BTW, congratulations, very cool app.Thanks.

Comment: i would call a realmService to update the Published var in the  func getDogs() .... I also convert the realm objects to normal structs or classes, easier to use in SwiftUI, a bit more code for converting thou.

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution but my work around was copying each realm result to a local object/array. I updated my Lists/Views to use the realmLocalData instead of the data returned from the realm object itself.

```
class ContentViewController: ObservableObject {
  private var realmLocalData: [ScheduleModel] = [ScheduleModel]()
  private let realm = try! Realm()

  func updateData() {
    realmLocalData.removeAll()
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateIndex >= %@ && dateIndex <= %@", argumentArray: [startDate, endDate])
    let data = self.realm.objects(MonthScheduleModel.self).filter(predicate)
 
    for obj in data {
      realmLocalData.append(ScheduleModel(realmObj: obj))
    }
  }
}
```